# In Github Actions, how do I modify an env. variable in the repository settings from a workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I just can get to modify an env. variable in the Repository Settings from a workflow.

In my repository settings I have created an Environment called "Development". In this environment I have added an env. variable called LastRunId.

I need to update the env. variable LastRunId in the Repository settings from the workflow that I am running.

From the workflow, I can successfully read LastRunId by using `${{ vars.LASTRUNID }}`

I now need to update this variable, but none of these are working:

```
${{ vars.LASTRUNID= "My-new-value" }}
${{ vars.LASTRUNID}} = "My-new-value"
```

I can't seem to find any example online of people trying to do this. There are plenty of examples on how to update env. variables declared inside the YAML file but nothing about how to update the variables in the Repository settings.

I have found these docs from Github indicating how to do it, but they don't seem to work either: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/variables?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-an-environment-variable

When I use the default env.GITHUB_TOKEN for the authorization, I get the error "Resource not accessible by integration" even though the Workflow Permissions are configured to "read and write permissions"

I have also tried creating a Personal Access Token with full permissions for everything, but then I get a "404 Not Found" when calling the Github API.

I've read that when calling the API I should use "token <GITHUB_TOKEN>" instead of "Bearer <GITHUB_TOKEN>" but that didn't work either.

The Actions from this repository would be exactly what I need, but internally they perform the operations by calling the Github API so these Actions also fail with the same error messages as when I call the API myself.
https://github.com/action-pack

I'm hoping someone else run into the same issue and could shed some light.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to sort it out.

The default GITHUB_TOKEN didn't have permissions to update either a Repository variable or an Environment Variable.

I had created Personal Access Tokens with full permissions but they didn't work at first because it turned out they needed to be approved by someone in my Organisation.

When I created the PATs, there was no warning in the UI that they needed to be approved. They showed as "created" and I only received an email to verify them, but no mention that they also needed to be approved by the Organisation.

They were approved and suddenly all the Github API calls started to work and also the actions from action-pack.

In particular, to update the env. variables in the repository settings, the token needs to have the scope "Variables" with the permissions set to "read and write" and the scope "Metadata" with "read-only". These scopes alone were sufficient to run the API calls and update the variables.

Hope it helps!